# display list of user in a AD group in azure web app

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-webapps

I am new to azure web app my use case is to display all the users present who belong to a single AD group in a web page. I have already tried to run the power shell command "**Get-azureaduser**" in my webapp controller but it is throwing me an error stating the "**poweshell workspace has to be run in admin mode**". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using? Most likely there is a Microsoft Graph SDK for it.

Comment: @juunas i am using C#

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code snippet using `Microsoft Graph SDK`

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var groups = await graphClient.Groups
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Another way you could try:

```cs
        string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token";
        var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

        //I am Using client_credentials as It is mostly recomended
        tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
            ["client_id"] = "b603c7be-a866_Your_Client_Id_6921e61f925",
            ["client_secret"] = "Vxf1SluKbgu_Client_Secret_SeZ8wL/Yp8ns4sc=",
            ["resource"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/" // If you use auth/V2.0 then use ["scope"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" 

        });

        dynamic json;
        AccessTokenClass results = new AccessTokenClass();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

        json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);


        //New Block For Accessing Group Data from Microsoft Graph Rest API
        HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups"));

        //Passing Token For this Request
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", results.access_token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        dynamic objAdGroupList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

*Class I have used:*

```cs
  public class AccessTokenClass
        {
            public string token_type { get; set; }
            public string expires_in { get; set; }
            public string resource { get; set; }
            public string access_token { get; set; }

        }
```

*Required permission On Azure Portal:*

> You should have `Application permission` `Group.Read.All,
>   Directory.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.AllDirectory.ReadWrite.All`
>   permission on azure portal.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

If you still have any concern please refer to [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and feel free to share.

Hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API [list group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http